# iPhone 5s calendar won't delete all events of the repeated event

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, calendar

I added one of my classes to my phone calendar and repeated it to every week.

For some reason I think it synced with my iCloud or uni site or something so all the details such as what room the tutorial is in, my teacher, what subject it is, etc, is all filled out in that event.

I had no problem with this in fact found it convenient. But the time of my tutorial has changed to a different day and now it seems that each of those class events are individual and not repeated.

When I delete one it doesn't prompt me to delete all future events.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem and delete all of these events at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Delete them one by one. I don't think it would be possible to delete all those events at once, because they are now not linked as a recurring event.

Comment: It may be possible, though, to use scripts on your Mac or PC (that syncs calendars via iCloud) to delete all events with the same name (even when they are not linked together).